# Error while running the apps llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode

when i run my app it gives the error like this.

> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: please add more details.. describe your code or situation where you encountered this error....

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I had a device chosen instead of a simulator. Try picking a specific device or specific simulator. If that doesn't work, try editing your scheme to make sure that the build configuration scheme (like, say, simulator) matches up the chosen device or simulator.